# object doesn't support property or method 'slice' jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

this is my controller code

```
 $scope.loadMajorObjects = function () {
      var appId = $scope.currentAppId;
      var type = $scope.majorObject.type;
      if (_.isEmpty(appId))
          return;
      var cacheKey = { key: cacheKeys.objectTypeList($scope.asCacheOptions({ ObjectType: type })) };
      return dataFactory.get("/MajorObject/All?applicationId=" + appId + "&type=" + type, { cache: cacheKey })
             .then(function (result) {
                 $scope.majorObjects = result.data.data;
                 $scope.majorObjectsList = $scope.majorObjects.slice(0, $scope.itemsPerPage);
                 $scope.totalItems = $scope.majorObjects.length;
                 $scope.isLoad = true;
             });
  };
```

and this is test case and in this i am calling $scope.loadMajorObject

```
describe("Testing MajorObjectsCtrl", function () {
    //checking dataFactory.get called only once
    it("should call dataFactory.get and called only once", function () {
        scope.currentAppId = mockApplicationId;
        scope.applications = applicationsMockData;
        scope.itemsPerPage = 10;
        $controller('AppSettingCtrl',
       {
           $scope: scope,
           dataFactory: mainmockdataFactory
       });
        expect(mockdataFactory.get.calls.count()).toBe(0);
        scope.currentAppId = mockApplicationId;
        scope.majorObjects.slice();
        scope.loadMajorObjects();
        scope.$digest();
        expect(mockdataFactory.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(mockdataFactory.get.calls.count()).toBe(1);
    });
```

when i call this function it is throwing and exception as object doesn't support property or method 'slice', how to rectify this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue currently. did you find any answers? I'm stuck.

Comment: @Maarten I deleted my other question, it's a repeat of this.